# how to write facade for reactjs 0.13 React.Component scalajs

Tags: scala.js

React.Component def : 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.component

ReactComponent api : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Examples :  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

What i tried so far ..

```
object React  extends js.Object{

  type Component[P,S] = ReactComponent[P,S]

}

class ReactComponent[P,S] extends js.Object {

  def this(props : P) = this()

  def setState(newState : S) : Unit = js.native

  def forceUpdate() : Unit = js.native

}
```

when i am trying this

```
 class Hello extends React.Component {

  }
```

i am getting undefined is not a function .  I am doing something terribly wrong! because i can't figure out right way...

Answer (score 1):

Since you define `type Component[P,S] = ReactComponent[P,S]`, Scala.js expects a class `ReactComponent` to be defined.

You must either:

- define `Component` inside `React` itself
- use `@JSName("React.Component")` on `ReactComponent`

Further,

```
class Hello extends React.Component
```

does not define a class that extends `React.Component`, but just another facade type. Therefore it does probably not do what you expect.

Comment: then how can i achieve something similar to class Hello extends React.Component ...

Comment: You currently cannot emit a ECMAScript 6 style class with Scala.js. You can chain prototypes as you would in ECMAScript 5. However, this will probably be very verbose. Consider using React's `createClass` function.

Comment: hmm we already have createClass code ,as part of upgrade github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/issues/95 i am trying this :)  , i think even js world using 6 to 5 transpilers !